# Champions League biggest comebacks after 1st leg

Tags: football, trivia, history, champions-league

Barcelona managed to beat PSG 6-1 in the second leg of 2017 round of 16 to win 6-5 on aggregate, having lost 4-0 in the first leg. Inspired by Barcelona' win, what are the biggest comebacks in champions league history after a loss in the 1st leg of knockout stage match?

Comment: This has already been answered here: http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15530/greatest-comeback-in-2nd-leg-match/15531#15531

Comment: Ah you're right, I guess it didn't pop up cause I started with "Champions league" on my question. I voted to close it. Should I just delete instead?

Comment: Took me a couple of searches to find it too. Given the phrasing, it may be worth keeping this post up, but closed and redirected to the other post.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with dupes - as Duncan notes, they act as useful pointers for people using slightly different words. No need to delete.

Comment: Would be nice if StackExchange would allow us to make these secondary question titles directly redirect to the same question (such that there were only one question to take space, but it'd be found either way) rather than have this second question sit around.  But given that it doesn't, I'm with Duncan/Philip, this is useful given the way the other question was worded.